# Is there a way to interchange between the Mist wallet and geth without having to redownload the whole blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, synchronization

I already have the ethereum wallet running on my laptop, when I exit it and go to run geth in terminal it redownloads the entire blockchain again? Same thing happens when I go from geth to the wallet.

Anyway to avoid this?

Comment: Can you provide some details on versions used, OS, if you are running both under the same user account, etc?

Comment: If you have a running geth instance, mist should simply connect to it. Maybe add some more details about your ethereum appdata directory structure, os, versions, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will re-download unless you specify a same `--datadir` for `geth` and Mist.

> See [How to set a different datadir in Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2551/259)

You can start geth using `--datadir "PATH/BASED/ON/OS"` flag to use the same blockchain.

Follow issue [#210](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/210) and [#70](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/70) both deals with the directory of the blockchain